# Hard Coding 2d array into a constructor

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to hard code a preset of values into a Constructor and it gives me an "illegal start message". If it doesn't allow that's fine I guess I'll try to find a work around. The program I am working on uses specific values for matrix1 that make the rest of the program work. I some what of a beginner so I may just be doing it wrong. I've looked in the Java API and found nothing saying I couldn't do what I want to do. I have a AssignmentOne class with the methods and constructor coded there and a AssignmentOneTest to test out the code. I would really like to use two classes for this.
 Below is my code:

```
public class AssignmentOne {
private double[][] matrix1;
private double[][] matrix3;

public AssignmentOne(){
  matrix3 = new double[3][3];
  matrix1 = {{0.9,0.05,0.05},
             {0.05,0.9,0.05},
             {0.05,0.05,0.9}};

}//Constructor END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only hard code the array where you declare it, not later on in your code. So this is OK:

```
public class AssignmentOne {
    double[][] matrix1 = {{0.9,0.05,0.05},
             {0.05,0.9,0.05},
             {0.05,0.05,0.9}};

    public AssignmentOne(){

        // now you are free to use matrix1 here if need be

    }
```

But this isn't:

```
public class AssignmentOne {
    double[][] matrix1;

    public AssignmentOne(){
      matrix1 = {{0.9,0.05,0.05},
                 {0.05,0.9,0.05},
                 {0.05,0.05,0.9}};        
    }
```

Another viable solution is to allow the constructor to accept an array parameter, and pass in the array that was initialized elsewhere, such as in the main method:

```
public class AssignmentOne {
    double[][] matrix1;

    public AssignmentOne(double[][] matrix1){
       this.matrix1 = matrix1; 
    }
```

Then elsewhere:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] arr = {{0.9,0.05,0.05},
             {0.05,0.9,0.05},
             {0.05,0.05,0.9}};

    AssignmentOne assignmentOne = new AssignmentOne(arr);
}
```

Comment: How could I use matrix1 in my constructor?

Comment: @JohnK: if you initialize it when you declare it, as in example at the top, you can use the array within the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `new double[][]` and `new double[]` I guess:

```
matrix1 = new double[][] {new double[]{0.9,0.05,0.05},
                          new double[]{0.05,0.9,0.05},
                          new double[]{0.05,0.05,0.9}};
```

And perhaps you forgot to close the first `}`. This is because we're talking about a variable altered by a method (yes a constructor is a method, the method that is executed immediately after an object is created), and thus the value can't be a constant. You need to use `new` to allocate it on the *heap*.

[**ideone demo**](http://ideone.com/VZpJCQ) (with different name)

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize array using constants in constructor. However, you can initialize it directly when declaring a variable

```
public class AssignmentOne {
    private double[][] matrix1 = {{0.90, 0.05, 0.05},
                                  {0.05, 0.90, 0.05},
                                  {0.05, 0.05, 0.90}};
    private double[][] matrix3;

    public AssignmentOne(){
        matrix3 = new double[3][3];
    }
}
```

Or, you can create it dynamicaly in constructor

```
public AssignmentOne(){
    matrix3 = new double[3][3];
    matrix1 = new double[][] {new double[]{0.90, 0.05, 0.05},
                              new double[]{0.05, 0.90, 0.05},
                              new double[]{0.05, 0.05, 0.90}};
}
```